# Allowing null value for association with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.6

I have a model relationship where a Team has many Users, but some Users haven't been assigned to a Team yet.

Is it possible to have an one-to-many association where the belongTo instance have null value for `teamId`?

I've tried the following:

```
User.associate = models => {
  User.belongsTo(models.Team, {
    foreignKey: { name: 'teamId', allowNull: true },
    constraints: false
  })
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: null value in column "teamId" violates not-null constraint

Comment: `constraints` should be in the `foreignKey` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had forgotten to add `allowNull: true` on the migration.